# Stuck at integrating worldpay

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, worldpay

I used the 
 **'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0’** in my whole app and now at the end i want to integerate the worldpay payment method but when i import the worldpay file i got this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libWorldpay.a(Worldpay.o)
      objc-class-ref in libWorldpay.a(ThreeDSController.o)
      objc-class-ref in libWorldpay.a(APMController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libWorldpay.a(WorldpayUtils.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I google it and try everything but nothing worked. Please tell me the solution. Thanks

Comment: Use `pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"` according to them that's working. https://github.com/Worldpay/worldpay-lib-ios Not with AFNetworking 3.0.

Comment: i tried it. Same error .